# How can I get source files from a compiled Electron application?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, macos, electron

how can I unpack a .app Application for Mac OS built with Electron? I want to view the source files, but I don't know how to access them.

Comment: -> _"electron unpack"_ / _"electron decompile"_

Comment: Thank you a lot! I was searching for these keywords.

Comment: to downvoters: i think this is a reasonable question for stackoverflow, and i don't see a duplicate, besides possibly [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56440355/how-to-unpack-a-single-exe-file-produced-by-electron-pack/56440638), but that one didn't receive any useful answers.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Generally, Electron apps are bundled using Electron's [`asar`](https://github.com/electron/asar) tool. Usually, you can unpack the source for these apps using the same tool.

If the app was bundled using a different tool, you will need to do your own research into whether the bundling process can be trivially reversed.

If you don't have `asar` installed, you can install it via `npm`:

```
npm install -g asar
```

Then try using `asar` to unpack the source:

```
cd /Applications/Slack.app/Contents/Resources
mkdir example-sourcecode
asar extract app.asar example-sourcecode
```

I found the above information on [this blog post](https://medium.com/how-to-electron/how-to-get-source-code-of-any-electron-application-cbb5c7726c37).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I get this error by doing so: "Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read"

Comment: @RedouanAzizim i'm sorry, i don't have a mac OS device to test with. it sounds like you might need to override some of the file permissions, or elevate your terminal session to a more privileged user.

Comment: Doesn't work. will give you ` [ERR_BUFFER_OUT_OF_BOUNDS]: Attempt to access memory outside buffer bounds` error.

Comment: Maybe try not doing it inside the Applications folder, which ordinarily requires administrator authentication to make changes to. Can you unpack to a different folder?